# Two urls for one website

Tags: permalinks, seo, rel-canonical

I have a customer that started his small business using an url called "firstname-lastname.ch". Since he was lucky enough to grow and now wants a proper URL, he would like to have another URL for his website called "businesstype-lastname.ch"

What would be the best way of achieving that without having too much administration and SEO issues.

Thanks!

Comment: PS both should be, SEO wise, as visible as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move the wordpress site to his new domain.
2. Make sure everything is working, hint: update all url's using [Velvet Blues Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/)
3. Point the old domain to a directory containing only two files:

A file named "index.php" containing:

```
<?php
$goto = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header( "Location: http://new-domain-name.ch" . $goto );
?>
```

And a file named ".htaccess" containing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now all traffic will be redirected to your new site, telling google to transfer the old sites value.

**Update: Canonical link rel**

You could also add this code to your existing sites functions.php (inside your theme), instead of completing step 3.

```
add_action('wp_head','rel_canonical');

function rel_canonical()
{
$goto = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$output = "<link rel='canonical' href='http://new-domain-name.ch/$goto' />";

echo $output;
}
```

This will dynamically output canonical links to all your Wordpress pages.

Comment: This will work, I was hoping to add a canonical tag to all pages via a plugin.

Comment: See my updated answer, which includes your request :)